# Solve Inverse Laplace Transform Using Input Integral Theorem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

### Problem

Using the input integral principle below

$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s} \mathscr{L} \left[ f(t) \right] (s), \ s > c $$

Find $ \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} \right](t) \ $ without using partial fractions.

### Attempt

Letting $ \ f(t) = \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} \right](t) $,

$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s} \mathscr{L} \left[ \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} \right](t) \right] (s), \ s > c $$

$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s}  \left[ \frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} \right], \ s > c $$

$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s^2(s^2+1)} , \ s > c $$

### Notes

Perhaps I've approached this problem incorrectly, but I'm confused as how to proceed with it. All I'm looking for is a hint or correct first step in solving this problem, with a little bit of explanation as to what the correct method toward solving this problem entails.

Also, I searched up what the *input integral principle* is and I'm not finding anything on it. Did my professor invent this name or is it an alias for something else?

That being said, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare these
$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s} \mathscr{L} \left[ f(t) \right] (s) $$
$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} \color{red}{\sin u} \ du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s} \color{red}{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)}}  $$

Comment: +1 color text makes things easy to understand

Comment: You really saved my as(ymptote) here––super descriptive, and I was able to just take the inverse Laplace transform of both sides to quickly get the solution described by the other answerers. Also, thanks for just providing a hint, as I was not looking for the full solution. Lastly, do you mind answering the last part of the question, at least to the best of your ability and with accuracy, before I mark this as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome and did you google "input integral principle" ?

Comment: Actually I haven't ever heard this name, but look at https://merounak.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/ordinary-differential-equation.pdf page 190.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The implied way is
$$ \mathscr{L} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(u)du \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s} \mathscr{L} \left[ f(t) \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{s^2+1} \implies \mathscr{L} \left[ f(t) \right] (s) = \frac{1}{s^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that your $$f(t)= \sin t $$ so  $$ \mathscr{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1}{s(s^2+1)} \right](t)=\int _0^t \sin u du = 1- \cos t$$